# Facebook apprequest not being sent to facebook users

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm developing a web app integrated with facebook and I'm using the request dialog to invite new users. So a user of my app can click on a button to send an apprequest to some of his facebook friends which are not users yet.

```
exports = fm.namespace(this,'bla','facebook')

exports['init'] = function(){
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    if (undefined !=RAILS_ENV['facebook_app_id'])
    {FB.init({
               appId      : RAILS_ENV['facebook_app_id'], // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
             });}
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
  }(document));
}
exports['sendRequestToOneRecipient']= function (uid) {
  FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    message: "bla bla",
    to: uid 
  }, requestCallback);

  function requestCallback(response) {
    if (response && response.to) {
      console.log("Message was sended"); 
    } else {
      console.log("Message was not sended.");
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I know it does not requiere any permissions because is a explicit action from the user. 
When a user clicks the button, the facebook window appears and everything is working fine. The callback is sending back the appId and the userid of the destinatary but the message is never being notifified in facebook destinatary account

No javascript errors on the console

Similary I'm posting to the wall of facebook friends and it is working without any issues. The same code but instead of 'apprequest', the method is 'feed'

Comment: everything seems correct... Is there any error showing?? Or just try to send a apprequest to a test account and check whether that request reached the test account through , graph api explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer - your query should be  https://graph.facebook.com/test_acc_id/apprequests

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I've check it up on the tool you sent me and the apprequests are there. I'm not using a test account. I' sending to my other facebook account. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: The data returned by the tool
 {
      "id": "315836123333964_100003158789166",
      "application": {
        "name": "XXX_test",
        "canvas_name": "XXX",
        "namespace": "XXX",
        "id": "161947XXX94867"
      },
      "to": {
        "name": "Juan Lab",
        "id": "100003153330166"
      },
      "from": {
        "name": "Miguel Martin",
        "id": "1383976222"
      },
      "message": "Hey,  check it out! :)",
      "created_time": "..."
    }, 

I don't know what are those canvas and namespace fields. Maybe I have  something left to configure on the facebook app??

Comment: On the configuration of my facebook app on facebook developers I have  the url site pointing to http://localhost:3000/ and also the domain to localhost. I don't know if with that configuration is not going to work properly

Comment: you can use any facebook account.. All looks good here also.. Has the other user (to whom you sent) got the notification or if that user already uses the same application , check the left navigation for any updates near to the app name!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the problem I've just marked my app as facebook application and added a canvas secure url, so when the user receives my apprequest it could be redirected to a valid site. As soon as I added that url, the users receive all the notifications.

The problem now, is that I have to create a specfic page to embeed as an iframe, because my website doesn't look proper as an iframe. Also I have to adquire a ssl certificate because canvas url must be https. If anyone knows a workaround, please let me know.

Thanks for your anwsers

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your template file:

```
if (top.location != self.location)
{
    top.location = self.location
}
```

If the location of the main website you're on isn't the same as your website's location it redirects you to your website.